# Doxygen - Inherit documentation from externally documented abstract class

Tags: inheritance, external, doxygen

I'm writing the documentation for my C++ class which inherits from an abstract class of which the documentation is already provided externally through a tag file.

I don't want to rewrite the documentation of several inherited functions as it would just be a copy-paste of the abstract parent ones. However, after specifying my tag file in the Doxygen configuration and enabling `INHERIT_DOCS`, the inherited documentation is still not present...

Am I missing some other parameter or could this be a limitation of Doxygen?

Directly processing the header file of the parent abstract class with Doxygen is working as expected (the documentation is included in the child class). Also, removing the declaration of the inherited function in my child class will add the function in the "Functions inherited from `ParentAbstractClass`"-group (but obviously not compile anymore).

Here is my working tree:

```
<root>
    +- ParentAbstractClass/
    |    +- html/
    |    |- ParentAbstractClass.tag
    |    |- ParentAbstractClass.hpp
    +- ChildClass/
    |    +- html/
    |    |- ChildClass.hpp
    |- Doxyfile_child
```

The content of `ParentAbstractClass.hpp`

```cpp
/**
 * @brief Parent class
 */
class ParentAbstractClass{
public:
    /**
     * Inherited function
     * @param[in] arg: input argument
     */
    virtual void inheritedFunction(const int arg)=0;
};
```

The content of `ChildClass.hpp`

```cpp
#include "ParentAbstractClass.hpp"

/**
 * @brief Child class
 */
class ChildClass : public ParentAbstractClass
{
public:
    // Following function should inherit the documentation from its parent
    virtual void inheritedFunction(const int arg); 
};
```

And some relevant (to my opinion) options in the `Doxyfile_child`:

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ChildClass
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
TAGFILES               = ParentAbstractClass/ParentAbstractClass.tag=../../ParentAbstractClass/html
```

I'm running Doxygen 1.8.14.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Could you give a small complete example?

Comment: I'm using version 1.8.14 and have just updated the question with C++ example code

Comment: The `INHERIT_DOCS` works inside one project. In the tag file, signaling an extrernal project, there is no information about the "parent" function. As soon as you add `/// \copydoc ParentAbstractClass::inheritedFunction(const int arg)` as documentation to the function in the ChildClass you will get "Implements ParentAbstractClass." with an reference to the function to the function in the ParentAbstractClass. (Note also that the reference to the tag file needs an extra level of `..` here, but this is not the cause of the problems).

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for as I would rather not write anything and get doxygen to 'automatically' link to it, but this is not possible as you point out.
I you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. (As for the extra `..`, they are not needed when running doxygen from the root directory: `doxygen Doxyfile_child`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INHERIT_DOCS` works inside one project.
In the tag file, signaling an external project, there is no information about the "parent" function. As soon as you add:

```
/// \copydoc ParentAbstractClass::inheritedFunction(const int arg)
```

as documentation to the function in the `ChildClass` you will get "Implements ParentAbstractClass." with a reference to the function to the function in the `ParentAbstractClass`.